# SFML - Able to open a new window but can't close it

Tags: sfml

I'm stuck on how to manage multiple windows in SFML. Basically, I'm able to open a new window, but it won't let me close it. Here is the new window header and implementation.
Header:

```
class PopWindow {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow popWin;
    sf::Color popWinColor = sf::Color(50, 50, 50);
    sf::Event popWinEvent{};

public:
    // Default constructor
    PopWindow();

    // While pop is Open
    int winOpen();
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "PopWindow.h"

PopWindow::PopWindow() {
  popWin.create(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Open Project");
}

int PopWindow::winOpen() {
  while (popWin.isOpen()) {
    while (popWin.pollEvent(popWinEvent)) {
      if (popWinEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::F2)) {
        popWin.close();
      }
      popWin.clear(popWinColor);
      popWin.display();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Weird thing is if I declare a PopWindow object in the main class file and call object.winOpen(), it works totally fine. However, if the object is declared in one of other class files, I can only open it but not close it.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that your function `winOpen` blocks the execution of all the program while the window is open (`while(popWIin.isOpen())`). So, without seeing the code that actually causes your problem, I'm guessing that you have some loop that doesn't let the execution even reach the code to close the window. You should use a debugger to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I copied that code and checked it out and I see that it works fine if you close the windows in the opening order. For example if you declared `window1` and `window2` and call `window1.winOpen()` and then `window2.winOpen()`, then until you close the first window - `window1` - the second not really started to handle closing event because `window1.winOpen()` did not finish yet. So you can drag the second window (which obviously opened on the first) aside and then close the first one and then close the second one.
But if you try to close the second before the first it will wait until you close the firs and then they both closed together.